# how to fix this bug in Laravel jetstream

Tags: laravel-8, laravel-9

How to fix this bug "@vite(['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'])"
And It seems CSS is not working in Laravel 8 and 9.
Laravel css not working, How to fix that ?

Comment: Try: composer require laravel/breeze --dev, php artisan breeze:install and then: npm install && npm run dev

Comment: Have you tried php artisan build command?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
npm install
npm run dev
npm run build

php artisan serve
```